# Join Three tables substraction in c# Windowform

Tags: c#

I have three tables Product,Purchase and Sale

```
Product
  Item_code    Item_Name
  1            Panadol
  2            Disprin
  3            Calpol
  4            Arinac

Purchase
  Item_code    Pur_Item_PackQuantity
      1             5
      1             4
      3             5
      4             6
 Sale
    Item_code   Item_Sale_Quantity
       1            5
       1            4
       3            5
       4            6
```

Now i want to get all Item_name from Product table and sum of Sale.Item_Sale_Quantity + Purchase.Pur_Item_PackQuantity from Sale and Purchase table but I am trying given below query which is generating error

```
   string query = "SELECT Product.Item_Name,Product.Packing,Product.MRP,SUM(Purchase.Pur_Item_PackQuantity)-SUM(Sale.Item_Sale_Quantity)AS[Stock] FROM Purchase RIGHT JOIN Product ON Product.Item_Code = Purchase.Item_Code Group By Item_Name  ORDER BY Item_Name ";

        SqlConnection newcon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=mateenwin;User ID=sa;Password=123");
        SqlCommand newcommand = new SqlCommand(query, newcon);
        SqlDataAdapter dp = new SqlDataAdapter(newcommand);
        DataTable dttt = new DataTable();
        dp.Fill(dttt);
        dataGridView3.DataSource = dttt;
```

Please help me for resolving this issue

Comment: what error is generated?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sql query fix.

```
select p.Item_Code, p.Item_Name, p.[Total],s.[Sold], p.Total - s.Sold as [Stock]
from (select pro.Item_Code, pro.Item_Name,sum(pur.Pur_Item_PackQuantity) as [Total] 
      from product pro left outer join purchase pur on pro.Item_code = pur.Item_Code
      group by pro.Item_Code,pro.Item_Name) as p
join (select pro.Item_Code ,sum(s.Item_Sale_Quantity) as [Sold] 
      from product pro left outer join sale s on pro.Item_Code = s.Item_Code
      group by pro.Item_Code) as s
on p.Item_Code = s.Item_Code
order by p.Item_Code asc
```

Comment: Dear Team This query is working and showing the Total and Sold  but Sum the Stock of only those records which are exist in sale table not other which are exist in purchase table but i want to sum the Stock of All records which are exist in Product table.

Comment: (Revised Comment) Dear Team This query is working and showing the Total and Sold  but Sum the Stock of only those records which are exist in sale and Purchase tables not other which are exist in purchase table but i want to sum the Stock of All records which are exist in purchase or sale table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your query as :

```
string query = "
SELECT Product.Item_Name, Product.Packing,
 Product.MRP,SUM(Purchase.Pur_Item_PackQuantity)-SUM(Sale.Item_Sale_Quantity)
 AS [Stock] 
FROM Purchase RIGHT JOIN Product ON Product.Item_Code = Purchase.Item_Code
Group By Item_Name,Packing,MRP  
ORDER BY Item_Name 
";
```